# When I press the left click site goes down

Tags: python, html, css

When I click on the left mouse button, the site takes me down, what could be the problem?

here is the link:
http://sakhalatin.pythonanywhere.com/

I tried everything I just started doing my website, I know that you will get shocked when you go to source HAAHHAHAHAHA

Answer (score -1):

I would guess the code at line 15 is the culprit:

```js
      window.addEventListener("click", function() {
        window.scrollBy(0, 1000); // значение "50" можно изменить на нужное вам количество пикселей, на которое нужно прокрутить страницу
      });
```

Comment: Yeah, I see the mistake thank you so much, I actually got rid of that code line in Xcode but not in the pythonantwhere. so silly...

Answer (score -1):

yes that does look like this is the problem

```
window.addEventListener("click", function() {
        window.scrollBy(0, 1000); // значение "50" можно изменить на нужное вам количество пикселей, на которое нужно прокрутить страницу
      });
```

Comment: thank you so much for your effort, I appreciate it;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).